# how to do healthcheck on salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Hi I have a critical application which talks to salesforce rest services .I need to do regular health checks programatically in this application so I can check if SF is up or not which shall signal further processing in my app.

Is there a url I can ping in SF for healthcheck ?

Comment: How about using one of relevant RSS feeds from http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/? Is it enough for you to know that instance doesn't have any issues or do you want to be able to log in to your particular org and get some info back?

Comment: actually the RSS feed there is useful ,had checked the same previously but we want to have an automated system in our app to ping a url in sf to check for downtime based on the response code . We are also thinking along the lines of creating a service to check the same but the issue can be the governance limits

Comment: That'd depend on how often you'd want to do it I guess, how many API calls are you willing to waste in it (rolling 24h limit). You could also look into exposing some simple VF page that confirms "it works" as Site (publicly visible without need to authenticate).

Comment: @eyescream that sounds to be a solution we were also thinking on similar lines .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't do it programmaticly, but I monitor https://naXX.salesforce.com (replace naXX with your server).

I also hope you don't mean a literal ping as this will respond even if there is an error page / webserver issue.  Monitor port 443 with HTTP.

Comment: Ya I am also doing it in a similar way currently